# Calculating responsivity

Tags: photodiode

My homework asks me to calculate "maximum responsivity" for a photodetector at frequency *F* Hz. Speed of light, Planck's constant, value of elementary charge, and Boltzmann constant are given. I know that responsivity should be calculated as $$R = \frac{\eta q}{hv}$$ The parameters are quantum efficiency, elementary charge, Planck's constant and frequency, respectively. How am I supposed to find the answer without knowing quantum efficiency? If I suppose quantum efficiency=1, I'll get an answer greater than 1, which is pretty weird because responsivity > 1 isn't physically realizable.

Comment: Responsivity equation simplifies to something like \$R \approx \eta \lambda/1.24 \$ *(wavelength is in micrometres, result in amps per watt)*. `responsivity > 1 isn't physically realizable` Why? or how? Responsivity has a unit of amperes per watt (or milliamps per milliwatt) which means an output photocurrent of 1 amp per one watt of incident optical power. So how or why isn't it practically realisable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum responsivity for a wavelength occurs occurs when the QE is 100%, meaning every photon generates a photoelectron.

As for a responsivity greater than one, it isn't clear why you think this isn't possible, but take a look at some photodiodes:

[image]

https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=285

A value greater than 1 simply means that the photon energy is low enough that 1 joule contains more than 1 Coulomb of photoelectrons, which will be the case for infrared photons.